# How to import an external jar file and export project as a file system in Eclipse

Tags: java, import, jar, export

I added an external jar file into my eclipse project from the properties>libraries in my project. Then I export my project as a file system, to make runnable for every computer. However after I import to project in eclipse, jar file refers to the my computers path thats why it does not work.

How should I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class path variable and refer to the JAR using a variable in the class path of your project. Each programmer can then set the variable according to theirs environment. Variables can be set in `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Classpath Variables` and used by pressing `Add Variable...` in Java Build Path editor of your project. When adding a variable to classpath, you can even press `Extend...` and "extend" your variable with a suffix - i.e. have the variable contain a folder name and suffix it with a fixed file name.

Some more obvious options:

- Copy the JAR inside your project, then export it.
- Agree on a common workspace structure and use a relative path to refer to the JAR.
- Use a dependency management tool (e.g. Maven).